# Corrupted Sdcard does not detect in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card

I have tired may answer provided for corrupted sdcard and below is command any output for the same :

[image]

My sdcard is 8 gb and i guess as shown in last command it is shown as sdb

When i insert sdcard it deetct for 1min and goes off below is screenshot :

[image]

[image]

Can anyone plz tell me is there any recovery point for the same?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your Card is poked - if it used to contain correct data, and that data is important, I'd try the following:

1. Back up the data - do something like "dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/corruptusb.iso" to copy the
   entire raw disk to a drive.  (If you have "PV" installed you can do it better by
   "pv /dev/sdb > ~/corruptusb.iso" which does roughly the same thing but will show you a
   progress bar.
2. Be prepared to loose the data on your SD card (hence backup above), and try running
   "testdisk"  (Part of the photorec suite) to see if it can find and rebuild your
   partition table - it appears this is corrupt/gone as there is no /dev/sdb1
3. If that fails, try run "Photorec" on the SSD to see what raw files you can pick up
   as a last resort.

Comment: Also note: The fdisk you did was on /dev/sda - the device of interest is /dev/sdb.   You could try and rebuild the data using fdisk or similar on /dev/sdb, but I would not recommend it as its likely to make things worse - and theoretically testdisk will do a better job.

Comment: m not interseted in data of sdcard...m just interseted to recover sdcard..the only question i hv is can u plz provide me some links explaining in breif 2 and 3 points in answer ...so that at any cost i can recovery my sdcard back...

Comment: thx for the answer , hoping a bit more information from you.

Comment: Your comments to nor make sense. Do you want to try get the data off the card or rsimply reinitialise the card? Also, how many times have you used it? ( I fear you may have been caught by a fake card - in which case most of your data is gone - some Chinese Ssd cards have much less memory then claimed and silently overwrite the disk when the real - small - memory is full. in this case you might only be able to get back very little raw data using photorec. Please Google Ubuntu photorec for more info on this software.)

Comment: If you want to recover your SD Card (and erase the data on it), and if the card is not a fake card, from the command line type "fdisk /dev/sdb", check the size of the device matches the size of the SD drive AND THAT IT DOES NOT MATCH THE HARD DRIVE - then create a partition table on it with the following sequence: n <enter> p <enter> 1 <enter> <enter> <enter> t <enter> b <enter> w <enter> - this will set up a new partition on the disk.  Then format it - mkfs.vfat del.me -  Remove and insert disk.  TEST THAT IT WORKS BY COPYING A LOT OF DATA TO IT AND SEEING IT SURVIVES BEING PLUGGED IN AND OUT

Comment: ..actually i just want to reinitialise the sdcard...the photorec does not detect my sdcard :(